# DKIM passes but SPF fails in policy_evaluated

Tags: email, spf, dmarc

The SPF failure is not preventing email from sending, but I'm curious if there's a way to get it to pass. Is there any scenario where an email server would reject receipt based on this DMARC record?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<feedback>  
  <report_metadata> 
    <org_name>Verizon Media</org_name>  
    <email>dmarchelp@verizonmedia.com</email>   
    <report_id>1619141439.695059</report_id>    
    <date_range>    
      <begin>1619049600</begin> 
      <end>1619135999</end> 
    </date_range>   
  </report_metadata>    
  <policy_published>    
    <domain>openpathtutoring.com</domain>   
    <adkim>r</adkim>    
    <aspf>r</aspf>  
    <p>none</p> 
    <pct>100</pct>  
  </policy_published>   
  <record>  
    <row>   
      <source_ip>12.345.678.90</source_ip>  
      <count>1</count>  
      <policy_evaluated>    
        <disposition>none</disposition> 
        <dkim>pass</dkim>   
        <spf>fail</spf> 
      </policy_evaluated>   
    </row>  
    <identifiers>   
      <header_from>openpathtutoring.com</header_from>   
    </identifiers>  
    <auth_results>  
      <dkim>    
        <domain>bnc3.mailjet.com</domain>   
        <selector>mailjet</selector>    
        <result>pass</result>   
      </dkim>   
      <dkim>    
        <domain>openpathtutoring.com</domain>   
        <selector>mailjet</selector>    
        <result>pass</result>   
      </dkim>   
      <spf> 
        <domain>bnc3.mailjet.com</domain>   
        <result>pass</result>   
      </spf>    
    </auth_results> 
  </record> 
</feedback>
```

SPF record:
`v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com ?all`

Comment: You could send an email to [Port25's DKIM checker](https://www.sparkpost.com/email-tools/authentication-checker/) and see what that reports.

Comment: @Robert thanks for sharing - everything passes on that report.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that SPF check is failing since the IP it is reporting for *is* included in the mailjet SPF, which covers `87.253.232.0-87.253.239.255` in its first subnet. I would expect it not to be counted because your SPF uses a default `?all` mechanism, which is about equivalent to not having an SPF record at all, plus your DMARC record says `p=none`, so you're asking receivers not to reject messages even if they fail to verify.

In short, I would not expect a mail server to reject anything on the basis of the settings you have.

Comment: The SPF record was specified by Mailjet. However, recently Mailjet has notified me that it is failing to send emails from no-reply@openpathtutoring.com because I haven't verified the email. I don't know where these emails are coming from, but I'm glad Mailjet is not permitting them to go through. Would revised SPF and DKIM records reduce the risk that a validated email is hijacked? I used the following tutorial to set up my email server, and I don't have a solid handle on how everything works (clearly)
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu